# iOS: Manually Push Locally Stored File to iCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, icloud

I have am application that uses a local data file to store user information and then show statistics of it. I store this file in my app's document folder as such ('dataArra' is an NSMutableArray):

```
// Define folder and file name
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
gameDataFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.dat"];

// Write content of 'dataArray' to locally stored file
[dataArray writeToFile:gameDataFile atomically:YES];
```

This works fine. But, since mine is a universal app, I would like this file to be shared between devices. However, I want my users to do this **manually**, ie. I do not want automatic iCloud synchronization. In other words, I would like to implement an "Upload" and a "Download" button and give users full control of when and if they want to sync this single file.

My problem is that the tutorials I have read all seem to focus on automatic synchronization; therefore, useless to me. Plus, they all seem to be overly complicated for my purposes. I got as far as enabling iCloud support in my app and then checking if it is indeed available with the following method (I also understand the basic idea behind iCloud and how it is supposed to work):

```
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) {
        NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
        // TODO: Load document...
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
    }
```

But, then I got lost in the ocean of, seemingly useless, information. Can anyone explain to me (in simple English) what methods need to be implemented in order to achieve the simple functionality described in my introduction? Or at least direct me to a good beginner tutorial that does a better job explaining the basics of iCloud than Apple's documentation (which I found not very helpful).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not finding this information is that you're trying to use iCloud in a different manner than it's designed to work. It's not a server that you upload data to and later download from. It's a background service on iOS that automatically syncs files which you tell it to sync. There is no "upload" or "download" API, instead there's API to mark files as ubiquitous (i.e. synced).

You can control when the initial download occurs. Use `NSMetadataQuery` to locate files in the user's iCloud account. Then use `[NSFileManager startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error:]` to initiate the download. Once the download is finished though, you have a ubiquitous file, and changes to the file sync automatically.

If you want a clean separation between synced data and non-synced local files, you'd probably need to make duplicate copies, and handle copying data between the synced copy and the non-synced one. Normally you'd save changes to the non-synced file. On "upload", you'd copy those changes to the synced version. On "download" you'd copy changes from the synced version to the local version. I'm not entirely certain that Apple would permit this, because it's not how they mean for iCloud to be used, but it's at least technically possible.